# D3.js tweening forward and backward to a specific point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

i just started playing around with Tweening in D3 and at start looked easy but now I'm struggling to achive this in my current code:

- Tweening to a specific point, example: from 0,0 to lineData[4]
- Tweening back to point 0,0 from lineData[4]

(Probably using buttons to control this)

This is my code at the moment: https://jsfiddle.net/uozko2bw/2/

```
//The data for our line
var lineData = [ 
{ "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
{ "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
{ "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

var lineFunction = d3.line()
 .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
 .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
 .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
 .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
 .attr("stroke", "blue")
 .attr("stroke-width", 2)              
 .attr("fill", "none");

 var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + lineData[0].x + "," + lineData[0].y + 
 ")");

 transition();

 function transition() {
  circle.transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(lineGraph.node()))
  .each("end", transition);
 }

 function translateAlong(path) {
 var l = path.getTotalLength();

 return function(d, i, a) {
   return function(t) {
     var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
     return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
   };
 };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `t` in the [interpolator](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_attrTween) typically goes from 0 to 1:

> The returned interpolator will then be invoked for each frame of the transition, in order, being passed the eased time t, typically in the range [0, 1].

Thus, you can simply call another interpolator with `t` going from 1 to 0:

```
var p = path.getPointAtLength((1-t) * l);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
//The data for our line
 var lineData = [ 
  { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
   { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
   { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

var lineFunction = d3.line()
     .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
     .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
     .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
     .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
     .attr("stroke", "blue")
     .attr("stroke-width", 2)              
     .attr("fill", "none");

var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + lineData[0].x + "," + lineData[0].y + ")");

transition();

/*
svgContainer.on("click", function() {
    transition();
});*/

function transition() {
  circle.transition()
      .duration(10000)
      .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(lineGraph.node()))
      .on("end", transition2);
}

function transition2() {
  circle.transition()
      .duration(10000)
      .attrTween("transform", translateAlong2(lineGraph.node()));
}

function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}

function translateAlong2(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength((1-t) * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: In D3 v4, it's `.on("end"...`, not `each("end"...`.

PPS: There is a lot of repetition in my solution. I'll let the DRY homework for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response Gerardo, it was very helpful.